# How to have Masonry adapt to the height of changing elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

So I have the following code:

```
function buttonBar(el) {
    $(el).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.entry', function(e){
        if(e.type == 'mouseenter'){
            $(this).find('.buttons').slideDown(120).fadeIn(80);
        }
        else if(e.type == 'mouseleave'){
            $(this).find('.buttons').slideUp(120).fadeOut(80);
        }
    });
}  
buttonBar('#posts');
```

Basically, when you hover over `.entry`, `.buttons` slides down. I am using Masonry and I was wondering if there was a way to get masonry to adapt to this on `mousenter` and `mouseleave`?

P.S: I hope this makes sense. I am a beginner at JQuery and very noob! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the `.buttons` set to `position: absolute;` so that they slide down over the other masonry elements. This will mean that they wont affect the height of other masonry elements.

**[Example JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8KAuG/1/)**

Or you could call `$container.masonry()` to [**get masonry to layout items**](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#layout) again after you have altered them.

Comment: I tried using this solution, but it would go all funny. Instead of moving down, the item below the one being hovered on would move up... ?

Comment: Ok, so I've tinkered with the JQuery a bit and this is the best I could come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/8KAuG/

notice how when you hover over `.entry`, `.buttons` comes down but there is delay time between this and the time it takes masonry to reconfigure.

Comment: This looks like it is working nicely. Unfortunately the delay will happen as masonry needs to recalculate positions off all elements when you change something.

Comment: No problem, i've also modified your code slightly to show the `position: absolute;` technique i spoke of. [**Find it here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8KAuG/1/)